# Can't display from remote host when running X, but can when running xinit

Tags: xorg, x11

I'm setting up [xdmx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdmx). I've got it working, and am now trying to get it to start automatically once both display server boot.

I want to avoid using xinit to start the backend X because I don't want xterm to run when I'm going to start xdmx.

But when I run just X and not xinit, I can't display from a remote host:

```
displayhost:~ # X &
displayhost:~ # export DISPLAY=:0
displayhost:~ # xhost +

clienthost:~ $ export DISPLAY=displayhost:0
clienthost:~ $ xterm
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: questek0.local:0
```

If I run `netstat -l` on the displayhost, I can see that it is listening on port 6000. I can also telnet to the displayhost port 6000 from the clienthost, so I don't think it is a network issue.

How can I get the above to work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the distro I'm working on (Open SuSE) has a /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc file that does some xauth things:

```
xauth -f $auth source - <<-EOF
add $tcpip $cookie
add $unix  $cookie
add ${host}/unix$dspnum $cookie
EOF
```

I now do something similar to this before I start the X server.